# Merge PDF's XARGS gs

Tags: pdf, merge, terminal, xargs

i try to combine several pdfs starting with "L" and ending with ".pdf" on my mac with terminal.
I tried the following

```
find . -name "L*.pdf" | xargs -0  gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -SDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=patternmerged.pdf
```

and i get the follwing output

```
Error: /undefinedfilename in (./L01_Introduction.pdf\n./L02_Edges, Corners, Superpixels and Blobs.pdf\n./L03_SIFT, SURF, MSER.pdf\n./L04_Texture and Shape.pdf\n./L05_Feature Reduction.pdf\n./L06_Bag of Visual Words.pdf\n./L07_Clustering...)

Operand stack:
Execution stack:
%interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2        %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push

Dictionary stack:
--dict:1167/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: No such file or directory
GPL Ghostscript 9.06: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Can Someone help?

Answer (score 0):

When using the `-0` parameter of xargs, it expects that the input arguments (filenames) are separated by null character, not by newlines.

To get the example above working, find could be used with the `-print0` option:

```
find . -name "L*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 -t gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -SDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=patternmerged.pdf
```

or the output of the find command could be preprocessed by `tr`, replacing newlines with null character:

```
 find . -name "L*.pdf" | tr '\n' '\0' |xargs -0 -t  gs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -SDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=patternmerged.pdf
```

Remark: 
with the `-t` parameter the xargs command is printed before execution.